# Python gtk: how to check if a combobox is open?

Tags: combobox, gtk, pygtk, selected

I am working on the graphical user interface of a machine. It uses comboboxes in a window that can be redrawn at any time in the main thread, outside the main loop (using the idle_add function inside the gtk-lock). This will happen when a certain button -a real one, not a widget- is pressed on the machine. If this happens while the combobox is open, I get a Gtk-Warning: assertion 'WIDGET REALIZED FOR EVENT' failed and my program hungs.

I tried to add the code:

```
    combo.set_active(-1)
    while gtk.events_pending():
          gtk.main_iteration()
```

but this didn't solve the problem.

I have been looking for functions like combo.is_open() or combo.close() but they don't seem to exist. The signals related to a combo are 'changed','move-active','pop-up' and 'pop-down' but the first is only sent when a text is selected in the combo and the other ones are keybinding signals.

Is there any way to check if a combo is open (has been selected) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `popup-shown` property.

The documentation even tells you to connect to `notify::popup-shown` which sounds like just what you need.

Comment: Thanks! I also found in your documentation the function `gtk_combo_box_popdown()` to close the combo. So this solves my problem..